# Querying mongo database based on formatted date?

Tags: mongodb

I have a data table showing a date formatted using moment.js. I have a filter on the table where plain text can be entered and I would like to filter the date column as well.

Client-side filtering is easy - I can just compare to the formatted value. Server-side, however, I am getting a little stuck. Is there any recommended way to do this without iterating over the list that comes back and checking against formatted value? If I knew that the filter value was in the expected format I could convert to a date, but ideally, the user should be able to type `1/` and have anything containing that string to return.

I'm thinking I will have to handle dates via a special date filter vs normal text

Comment: can you tell in what format is the date filed in your collection?

Comment: I just have the default date format that mongo uses (which is just javascript Date object as far as I can tell)